# $X$ a finite set and $A_1,A_2,...,A_r$ be subsets of $X$ of size $m$. If $r < 2^{m-1}$, then $\exists$ a $2$-coloring of $X$ s.t. no $A_i$ is mono.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, ramsey-theory

Monochromatic. I want to find a non-probabilistic proof of this statement, because I already know a probabilistic one. The probabilistic proof basically uses the fact that $P(Y \leq E[Y])>0$ for a random variable $Y$. We color the elements of $X$ uniformly and get that the expected number of monochromatic subsets is $1$...

Comment: I guess there is some quantifier missing here. Do you mean the set $X$ and the values of $r$ and $m$ are fixed and you are supposed to show that you can avoid monochromatic subsets no matter how you pick the $A_i$ or what?

Comment: There is no quantifier missing, okay m has to be larger than 1, and r larger than 0. The point is, however you choose the A_i's with whatever m, if r is smaller than above value, you can choose a 2coloring s.t. no A_i is mono

Comment: It's true for general m.

Answer (score 1):

The natural argument to make here is probabilistic, so you may or may not think of these alternatives as "thin disguises":

**Proof 1.** There are $2^{|X|}$ colorings of $X$. For each $i$, there are $2^{|X|-m+1}$ "bad" colorings where $A_i$ is monochromatic. Altogether, the number of bad colorings is at most $r \cdot 2^{|X|-m+1}$, which is less than $2^{|X|}$, so some "good" colorings must also exist.

**Proof 2.** We will color the elements of $X$ one at a time, and assign each set $A_i$ a danger level that we update as we go. Initially, each $A_i$ has danger level $1$. Whenever an element of $A_i$ is colored:

- If $A_i$ now has elements of both colors, its danger level is permanently set to $0$.
- If the newly colored element is the first element of $A_i$ we colored, its danger level is unchanged.
- If $A_i$ already had elements of the color we used just now (and no elements of the other color), its danger level doubles.

Whenever we color $x \in X$, some of the $A_i$'s might double in danger level and others will have their danger level set to $0$. If we change the color we use on $x$, that exactly swaps which danger levels double and which danger levels get set to $0$. Therefore whatever the two possible **total changes in danger level** are when we color $x$, they are equal and opposite in sign.

We choose our colors so that at every step, the total danger level does not increase. Initially, the total danger level is equal to $r$, so at the end it is at most $r$. This means that we cannot end with a monochromatic $A_i$: such an $A_i$ would have a danger level of $2^{m-1} > r$ all on its own, since its danger level would have doubled $m-1$ times.

Comment: The motivation is probabilistic: the danger level of a set $A_i$ is proportional to the probability that it's monochromatic in a random completion of the coloring, and so the algorithm is based on making sure the expected number of monochromatic sets never goes up. This is a way of derandomizing algorithms based on expected value that shows up in many places; recently, I've seen a very nice write-up of it in Schöning and Torán's book *The Satisfiability Problem*.

Comment: (See above for answer) I'm wondering the motivation for Proof 2?  I haven't seen this type of argument before.  It took me a moment to recognize that the danger level for $A_i$ will either double or lose all its value.  This method gives an algorithm to find a desired coloring.